# Issue with Next/Script in NextJS 13 app router

Tags: next.js13, app-router

I want to execute a script from the **public** directory. However, no matter how I pass the src to , it returns 404 error, indicating that the file does not exist, although the file exists in the public directory.

Here is a very simple example:

```
    const Home: NextPage = async () => {

     return (
      <>
       <Script src="/static/example.js" />

       <HomePage />
      </>
    );
   };

   export default Home;
```

Does anyone know how to handle this issue?
I am using next version **13.5.3**

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap the Script component with `Head` component from `"next/document"`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).